# Am I right with my explanation of print.__call__.__call__("Hello World")?

Tags: python, function

So because many things in Python are objects including functions one can do this:

```
print.__call__.__call__("Hello World")
```

This works because `print` is a function object and hence has the `__call__` function object attribute which is also a function object which also has a `__call__` function object.

Hence when we run this code we are calling the first `__call__` function object by calling its `__call__` funciton object with the argument `"Hello World"` which then calls the `__call__` function object (ut calls the function object it resides in - the point of `__call__`) and whne this happens, the first `__call__` function object then is called using the arguments sent by the second `__call__` object ("Hello World") which then calls the function object that it resides in which is `print` with the arguments that the first `__call__` was called with which is `"Hello World"` hence printing out `"Hello World"`.

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you. I appreciate that a lot. The fact that people will take time out of their day to help someone not cry themselves to bed. But really thanks :).

Comment: There is more to it though. To look up `__call__` it will use `__dict__` and maybe `__getattr__`.

Comment: Okay. I guess so, internally how it works. But I needed to me sure my general understanding was correct. Thanks man.